# Scroll back to top of triggerElement with scrollmagic on scroll after scrolledTo next element's top

Tags: jquery, scroll, slide, scrolltop, scrollmagic

I have a bit of problem with scrollMagic hope you could help me out...
I have 2 div's on my page with full height and after that comes the rest of the site
what I'm trying to do is that I want to slide the first two divs down on scroll down and to their top on scroll up and continue scrolling normally after scrollTop reaches to the bomttom of my second div.
[exactly like this site](https://aeropersia.com/)
as you already know I can't use something like fullpage.js because it changes the way of scrolling completely.

to give you a better perspective here is a little simulation of my structure

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <menu>

        ...

    </menu>
    <main>
        <div class="full-height-div-1">

            Some content ...

        </div>
        <div class="full-height-div-2">

            Some other content ...

            <div class="none-full-height-content-wrapper">

                The rest of the elements

            </div>

        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>

        ...

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried scrollmagic and now when I scroll down and hit the trigger it slides to the top of the second div just fine but don't know how to tell it to slide back up if I scroll up

here is my js:

```
scrollTriggers : function() {

        myOffset = $j(window).height();
        if( $j( 'body' ).hasClass(app.vars.homePageClass) ){
            var homeController = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
        }

        var fullHeightPageScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: '.content_wrapper',
            triggerHook: 0.95,
        })
        .on('enter', function() {
            TweenMax.to(window, 1, {scrollTo: '.content_wrapper'})
        })
        .on('leave', function() {

            if( app.vars.newScrollTop < app.vars.contentWrapperElement.offset().top )
            {
                TweenMax.to(window, 1, {scrollTo: app.vars.introSection})
            }
        })
        .addIndicators()
        .addTo(homeController);

        var fullHeightPageScene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene( {
            triggerElement: app.vars.introSection,
            triggerHook: 0,
            duration: '90%',
            // offset: myOffset - 10,
        })
        .on('enter', function() {
            if( app.vars.newScrollTop < app.vars.contentWrapperElement.offset().top )
            {
                TweenMax.to(window, 1, {scrollTo: app.vars.introSection})
            }
        })
        .addIndicators()
        .addTo(homeController);
    },
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear enough
and thank you in advance

Comment: *"I can't use something like fullpage.js because it changes the way of scrolling completely."* That's not totally true. 
You can solve it by using `scrollBar:true` as in [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html). You will keep having the auto scroll feature this way and be able to use scroll  magic if you wish.

Comment: @Alvaro Thank you I will definitely check this out, but I still need to know how to do this with only scrollmagic for two reasons first to avoid using too many js plugins specially the ones that mess with scrolling and second I've seen this done with scrollmagic and I want to learn how.